# MySQL: Declare a cursor for `show tables`?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I want to write a stored proc which iterates through all of the tables in my database and performs some action.

```
drop procedure if exists p2;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `p2` ()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'A procedure'
BEGIN
declare cur1 cursor for
    show tables from my_database_name
END//


call p2;
```

This is not working; I get an error saying I have an error in SQL syntax near 'show tables from my_database_name'

Of course, instead of doing `show tables from my_database_name` I really want to say `show tables from database()` or `show tables from (select database())`, neither of which work.

Help? Can I do this in straight SQL or do I need to first call `show tables` from my program and then iterate through the result set there? How can I create a cursor to capture the values of things like `database()` or `show tables`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show tables` isn't a SQL query — it's handled in a different way — but you can query [the tables in the `information_schema` database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html). You need something like `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='db_name'`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! In this case, I am able to replace `db_name` with `database()` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that gives you counts for all of your tables.

```
DELIMITER $$                                                                                                                                                                    

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procCountAllTables $$                                                                                                                                  

CREATE PROCEDURE procCountAllTables()                                                                                                                                           

BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                           
        DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);                                                                                                                                        
        DECLARE end_of_tables INT DEFAULT 0;                                                                                                                                    

        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR                                                                                                                                                  
            SELECT t.table_name                                                                                                                                                 
            FROM information_schema.tables t                                                                                                                                    
            WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE() AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE';                                                                                                    
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_of_tables = 1;                                                                                                           

        OPEN cur;                                                                                                                                                               

        tables_loop: LOOP                                                                                                                                                       
            FETCH cur INTO table_name;                                                                                                                                          

            IF end_of_tables = 1 THEN                                                                                                                                           
                LEAVE tables_loop;                                                                                                                                              
            END IF;                                                                                                                                                             

            SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ''', table_name, ''', COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ' , table_name);                                                                               
            PREPARE stmt FROM @s;                                                                                                                                               
            EXECUTE stmt;                                                                                                                                                       

        END LOOP;                                                                                                                                                               

        CLOSE cur;                                                                                                                                                              
    END $$                                                                                                                                                                      

DELIMITER ;
```